swagger editor in windows
following this section and trying to get it to run in windows : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor?tab=readme-ov-file#docker
I cannot get the equivalent command of
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -v $(pwd):/tmp -e SWAGGER_FILE=/tmp/swagger.json swaggerapi/swagger-editor

to work in a windows command prompt
I would think the equivalent is
docker run -d -p 80:8080 -v %cd%:/tmp -e SWAGGER_FILE=/tmp/swagger.yaml swaggerapi/swagger-editor

but that does not work

You don't provide much information about your environment so I am assuming you are trying to run it using a Windows docker host.
This is not possible since the Windows docker host can only run docker images based on Windows and the image you are trying to run is Alpine Linux based.
If you want to run this image you will need to run it on a Docker host installed within WSL2.
